# How to create a one to many relationship which point from a table to the same table?

Tags: django

I have a table employees with employee_id as a primary key, some of the employees are managers and managers can also have managers.

So I wanted to add a manager_id field to the table employees which is the employee_id of the manager of the employee. I tried to create a one to many relationship between the table and itself but without success.

In the employees class I have added the following:

```
id_manager = models.ForeignKey(employees, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

NameError: name 'employees' is not defined
```

I am pretty new to django, any idea how to code this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) covers this case explicitly:

> To create a recursive relationship – an object that has a many-to-one relationship with itself – use `models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.